# iPhone video recording app with label on top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation

The idea of the app is that the phone records some footage and on top of that should be a label which changes value throughout the filming process. How can the label be added on to the final movie? Is it possible to directly integrate the label to the movie while recording? Any helpful tips or links will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check AVFoundation's reference of [AVAssetWriter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Besides that, there are plenty examples and questions out there on that component - also here on StackOverflow.